# How can I convert a column to int if it contains NaNs?

Tags: python, pandas, integer, nan

I am working on this `efw` data frame:

```
2   Year    ISO_Code    Countries   INDEX   Rank    Quartile
3   2016    ALB         Albania     7.54    34      1
4   2016    DZA         Algeria     4.99    NaN     4
5   2016    AGO         Angola      5.17    155     4
6   2016    ARG         Argentina   4.84    160     NaN
7   2016    ARM         Armenia     7.57    NaN     1
8   2016    AUS         Australia   7.98    10      1
9   2016    AUT         Austria     7.58    27      NaN
```

Let's say that I want to convert all the values in the `Rank` and `Quartile` columns into integers if the are not a `NaN`. I have tried `efw[["Year", "Rank", "Quartile"]].astype(int)` but keep getting this error: `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Is there a way to tell Python to "skip" the `NaN` values and only convert the others into `int`?

Comment: Add a filter using the `isnull()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Prune ! How would the line look like? `efw.insnull(efw[["Year", "Rank", "Quartile"]].astype(int))` ?

Comment: `efw[['Year', 'Rank', 'Quartile']].isnull()`. Or you can use `sum` as well if you want to see total count of NaN value for each columns. Just like `efw.isnull().sum()`

Comment: What is your current column dtype?

Comment: It's coming in next version of pandas.      http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew.html#optional-integer-na-support   Otherwise np.nans force column to be floats.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert them into `object`

```
efw[["Year", "Rank", "Quartile"]].astype(object)
Out[58]: 
   Year Rank Quartile
0  2016   34        1
1  2016  NaN        4
2  2016  155        4
3  2016  160      NaN
4  2016  NaN        1
5  2016   10        1
6  2016   27      NaN

#efw[["Year", "Rank", "Quartile"]]=efw[["Year", "Rank", "Quartile"]].astype(object)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Just reproduced your requirement, here are few way to do this, However i see you have already an integer values in place and only missing ones places as `NaN` which you can convert into int or say `zero` as those are missing.

```
    >>> efw
   Year ISO_Code  Countries  Index Rank Quartile
0  2016      ALB    Albania   7.54   34        1
1  2016      DZA    Algeria   4.99  NaN        4
2  2016      AGO     Angola   5.17  155        4
3  2016      ARG  Argentina   4.84  160      NaN
4  2016      ARM    Armenia   7.57  NaN        1
5  2016      AUS  Australia   7.98   10        1
6  2016      AUT    Austria   7.58   27      NaN
```

**Method 1**

Straight from the pandas documentation even we have better way of doing, [Document Link For pandas.DataFrame.fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

So, As you have multiple columns, but only want to replace the NaN in a subset of them, you can use, I would say better would be to replace `NaN` to `0` rather skipping as blank..

```
>>> efw.fillna({'Rank':'0', 'Quartile':'0'}, inplace=False)
   Year ISO_Code  Countries  Index Rank Quartile
0  2016      ALB    Albania   7.54   34        1
1  2016      DZA    Algeria   4.99    0        4
2  2016      AGO     Angola   5.17  155        4
3  2016      ARG  Argentina   4.84  160        0
4  2016      ARM    Armenia   7.57    0        1
5  2016      AUS  Australia   7.98   10        1
6  2016      AUT    Austria   7.58   27        0
```

If you want to make the changes to be permanent in the DataFrame then you can use:

```
>>> efw.fillna({'Rank':'0', 'Quartile':'0'}, inplace=True)
>>> print(efw)
```

**Method 2**

You could check `dtype` whether it's numeric or not with `dtype.kind` using `apply` for your columns as follows..

> ```
> *dtype.kind:* A character code (one of ‘biufc’) identifying the general kind of data.
>
> b boolean
> i signed integer
> u unsigned integer
> f floating-point
> c complex floating-point
> ```

Hence, you can use apply with lambda function as follows ..

```
 >>> efw.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(0) if x.dtype.kind in 'biufc' else x.fillna('0'))
   Year ISO_Code  Countries  Index Rank Quartile
0  2016      ALB    Albania   7.54   34        1
1  2016      DZA    Algeria   4.99    0        4
2  2016      AGO     Angola   5.17  155        4
3  2016      ARG  Argentina   4.84  160        0
4  2016      ARM    Armenia   7.57    0        1
5  2016      AUS  Australia   7.98   10        1
6  2016      AUT    Austria   7.58   27        0
```

**Method 3**

OR With your dataframe you simply use `DataFrame.fillna()`  method. This will convert all NaN into zero irrespective of Columns you have.

```
>>> efw.fillna(0)
   Year ISO_Code  Countries  Index Rank Quartile
0  2016      ALB    Albania   7.54   34        1
1  2016      DZA    Algeria   4.99    0        4
2  2016      AGO     Angola   5.17  155        4
3  2016      ARG  Argentina   4.84  160        0
4  2016      ARM    Armenia   7.57    0        1
5  2016      AUS  Australia   7.98   10        1
6  2016      AUT    Austria   7.58   27        0
```

**Note:** You can use `fillna('')`  rather  `fillna(0)` if you want to remove `NaN` and make it blank.